# Concat two SELECTS from different tables with different columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got two tables.

first

```
payout_id
partner_id
bank_account_id
old_balance
amount
status
manager_id
comment
creation_time
update_time
```

second

```
payment_id
advertiser_id
type
bank_account_id
amount
status
manager_id
comment
creation_time
update_time
```

I've ended up with concatenation of these stuff. These tables don't share any data. I need to sort the result by `update_time` and apply pagination. Structure is almost similar except the first two columns and one in the middle, so I need just add them leaving one of distinct blank relatively to the table. But the query like

```sql
SELECT payment_id FROM `advertisers`.`payments`
UNION
SELECT payout_id FROM `partners`.`payouts`
```

or

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT payment_id FROM `advertisers`.`payments`
    UNION
    SELECT payout_id FROM `partners`.`payouts`
) t
```

shows only the first `SELECT`'s result.

Quick googling didn't help. Is it even possible? I don't like the idea to do it in the code...

Comment: Can you add the expected output result set example

Comment: One possibility is that selected `payment_id` and `payout_id` matches in value and the `union` caused omitting the duplicate row. Try with `union all` and see what the result is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to make them at least look like they have the same columns.

You can either put defaults in or adjust the names...

Example (it seems volatile to union them under the same column?!)

```
SELECT payment_id FROM `advertisers`.`payments`
UNION
SELECT payout_id AS payment_id FROM `partners`.`payouts`
```

Or

```
SELECT payment_id, 0 AS payout_id FROM `advertisers`.`payments`
UNION
SELECT 0 AS payment_id, payout_id FROM `partners`.`payouts`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 'payout' kind,  payout_id,  partner_id, bank_account_id, NULL,          NULL, NULL,            old_balance, amount, status, manager_id, comment, creation_time, update_time FROM `partners`.`payouts`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'payment' kind, payment_id, NULL,       NULL,            advertiser_id, type, bank_account_id, NULL,        amount, status, manager_id, comment, creation_time, update_time FROM `advertisers`.`payments`
) Q
ORDER BY update_time
```